# How to handle Server side Exception in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, pdo

How can I handle the Server Side Exception on Laravel? 
I am creating an update API and I am passing a wrong value to handle exception but I am unable to catch that Error using the try-catch block. Can someone help me? 
Below is the code :

```
{
"user_id" : "15835943395e63bb63c449d",
"changes" :{
    "username" : "new username",
    "name" : "new name",
    "statuss" : "inactive"
}
}
```

So As you can see I am trying to pass an Invalid field i.e **status** actual is **status**.

here is my code to handle this :

```
try{
            $json = json_decode($changes,true);
            $update = 'SET ';
            $columns = [];
            $values = [];
            $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
            foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
                $columns[]=$key;
                $values[]=$value;
                $update .= $key . '=?,';
            }
            $update = substr($update, 0, -1);
            $sql = "update users ".$update." where user_id='".$request->input('user_id')."'";
            $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(\PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => \PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
            $sth->execute($values);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e;
        }
```

But I am not getting anything on the postman.

Here is the snapshot :

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to catch any `sql` syntax or query errors is to catch an `Illuminate\Database\QueryException` after providing closure to your query:

```
try { 
   $json = json_decode($changes,true);
        $update = 'SET ';
        $columns = [];
        $values = [];
        $pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();
        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            $columns[]=$key;
            $values[]=$value;
            $update .= $key . '=?,';
        }
        $update = substr($update, 0, -1);
        $sql = "update users ".$update." where user_id='".$request->input('user_id')."'";
        $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(\PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => \PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        $sth->execute($values);
} catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ 
  dd($ex->getMessage()); 
  // Note any method of class PDOException can be called on $ex.
}
```

If there are any errors, the program will `die(var_dump(...))` whatever it needs to.

Note: For namespacing, you need to first `\` if the class is not included as a `use` statement.

Also for reference: [Laravel 6.x API - Query Exception](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/QueryException.html)

Comment: Thanks @Ronak. I will check this

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I am a fan of @Ronak's answer for the SQL end, if you wanted to catch the error before any SQL was executed you can use the in built validate method to check API parameters before executing code. The great thing about this is you can require not only which parameters are present but also what the value should be - check [here](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation) for more info.

In you controller:

```
public function validateRequest(Request $request) 
{
    $rules = ['status' => ['required', Rule::in(['inactive', 'active'])]];
    $messages = ['status' => 'Status is a required parameter and must be either inactive or active'];
    $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
}
```

Then in your try block simply

```
try {
     $this->validateRequest($request)
     // ... rest of code goes here
} catch (Exception $e) {
     return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 200); // response()->json() is a facade to return a JSON response 
}
```